# Error::::Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719665/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle)

When I click on update button I get this error 
My update click event

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gr = gvResTasks.Rows[idx];
```

When  `idx` value is up to 19 it works fine.  When it is greater than 19 this error occurs.

Updatebutton.aspx

```
<ItemTemplate> 
  <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" OnCommand="btnUpdate_Click" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" /> 
  <%--<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Update" onclick="btnUpdate_Click" />--%> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

updatebutton.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   // int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    int idx = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow gr = gvResTasks.Rows[idx];

    Label hf = (Label)gr.FindControl("hdEmployeeID");

    string sEmpID = hf.Text;
    lblEmployeeID.Text = sEmpID;
    lblEmployeeID2.Text = sEmpID;

    int Rows = gvResTasks.Rows.Count;
    for (int x = 0; x < Rows; x++)
    {
        GridViewRow tr = gvResTasks.Rows[x];
        tr.CssClass = "WhiteBack";
    }

    ClearMessages();

    gr.CssClass = "TealBack";

    string sSubTaskID = gr.Cells[0].Text;
    lblSubTaskID.Text = sSubTaskID;

    lblSubTaskName.Text = @gr.Cells[1].Text;

    LoadSubTaskInfo();

    Single sProgress = 0;
    Boolean bok = Single.TryParse(lblActualProgress.Text, out sProgress);

    DateTime dPF = DateTime.Parse(lblPlannedFinish.Text);

    if (dPF > DateTime.Now)
    {
        btnFinish.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (dPF <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        if (sProgress >= 100)
        {
            btnFinish.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            btnFinish.Enabled = true;
        }
        //btnFinish.Enabled = true;
    }

    panelUpdate.CssClass = "float";
    panelUpdate.Visible = false;
    if (gr.Cells[7].Text != "True")
    {
        panelUpdate.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not it same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719665/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-colle?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch a value from gvResTasks which is at a place in the gridView higher than the row count in it. Hence the error that the index is out of bounds.